# Dynamically creating and storing an algorithm at runtime

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, functor, qt-quick

Suppose I have some functions written and compiled in C++:

```
int quicksum(int a, int b){ return a+b; }
int quickmult(int a, int b){ return a*b; }
```

At **runtime**, I'd like to be able to create a combination of these functions, such as `quicksum(quickmult(5,6),7)` and keep that around as a saved procedure that I could execute any time.

Currently, I'm getting halfway there by using JavaScript and C++ together in Qt, where functions like `quicksum` are defined in C++, and then invoked from JavaScript by doing this:

```
    var somestring="quicksum(5,(quicksum(4,4)))"
    eval(somestring)
```

Now that works, but the problem is that the combination of these functions is still being managed on the JavaScript side, which means that JS is handling the return from one function before inputting it into another function, rather than C++ running the entire combination itself (at least I assume that to be the case).

I don't mind creating the initial combination in JS but for performance reasons I don't want JS involved every time I need to call the combination of functions.

Is there a way to somehow get this combination of functions into the C++ side and have it stay there for running later? I don't mind taking JS out of the process entirely, it's just the only method I could think of; perhaps there is some clever way of using functors in C++ for dynamically stitching together functions at runtime that have been previously compiled?

Update...

Another option I am considering is to use functors that themselves have member variables that refer to other functors. This would be a bit like creating a new function with a closure at runtime if the JS called a functor constructor with parameters of other functors. Then this functor would entirely be a C++ object with the procedure stored within (I think). I will need to work this out in my head for a bit.

Comment: Look into expression templates (if you dare).

Comment: If your expression strings are valid C++, you can compile them and then dynamically load the binary. Your JS solution isn't bad -- JS is pretty fast these days.

Comment: @amwinter the problem is that the JS strings are created at runtime, not compile time, so C++ cannot get them during compilation

Comment: @OpenLearner, Ah, I might have misunderstood your requirements somewhat.

Comment: @OpenLearner I meant you can compile a library module using the user-provided expression string, then load it into your running process and call it like a function. This isn't safe, but it may do what you want.

Comment: @amwinter but if the user-provided string occurs during runtime, how am I to compile new c++ code while the program itself is running?

Comment: @OpenLearner you'll have to paste it into a C++ function, write the function to a file, run your compiler on the file, then use LoadLibrary or your system's equivalent to bring the new module into your running process. I'm not recommending this -- I suspect the JS solution you have is pretty fast.

Comment: @OpenLearner it's also worth doing some reading about LLVM and runtime code generation.

Comment: @amwinter thanks.. the issue is that I've already found JS to be a bottleneck in other similar ways in my app, where these calculations must happen many times a second, so i want to avoid too much dependence on realtime Js interpreting

Comment: @OpenLearner you may get some edge from embedding v8 or spidermonkey instead of QT -- JS compiler technology is constantly advancing.

Comment: @amwinter V8 is the engine Qt uses in 5.0 and 5.1, so I'm using that now.

Comment: @OpenLearner are you calling `eval` every time, or are you calling `Script::Compile` and then `Run()`ing the handle object?

Comment: @amwinter just using eval. Do You recommend the other method you describe?

Comment: @OpenLearner not sure if it will really be faster (`eval` may be caching), but worth a shot. One problem: I'm assuming your function arguments are changing. I'm not sure if `Run()` will let you pass in new arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluating a run-time constructed function is not going to be “quick” in any reasonable sense of the word, unless you go full out and compile it, e.g. to a dynamic library.

Barring that you can just construct a dynamic expression tree.

You will probably want to add a bit of syntactic sugar compared to the code below, but it shows the basics:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>   // std::plus, std::multiplies
#include <memory>       // std::unique_ptr
#include <utility>      // std::move
using namespace std;

struct Expression
{
    virtual auto eval() const -> double = 0;
    virtual ~Expression() {}
};

struct Number: Expression
{
    double      value;

    auto eval() const -> double override { return value; }

    Number( double v ): value( v ) {}
};

struct Binary_op: Expression
{
    unique_ptr<Expression>  a;
    unique_ptr<Expression>  b;

    Binary_op( unique_ptr<Expression> _a, unique_ptr<Expression> _b )
        : a( move( _a ) ), b( move( _b ) )
    {}
};

template< class Impl >
struct Concrete_binary_op: Binary_op
{
    auto eval() const -> double override
    { return Impl()( a->eval(), b->eval() ); }

    Concrete_binary_op( unique_ptr<Expression> _a, unique_ptr<Expression> _b )
        : Binary_op( move( _a ), move( _b ) )
    {}
};

using Sum       = Concrete_binary_op<std::plus<double>>;
using Product   = Concrete_binary_op<std::multiplies<double>>;

auto number( double v )
    -> unique_ptr<Number>
{ return unique_ptr<Number>( new Number( v ) ); }

auto sum( unique_ptr<Expression> a, unique_ptr<Expression> b )
    -> unique_ptr<Sum>
{ return unique_ptr<Sum>( new Sum( move( a ), move( b ) ) ); }

auto product( unique_ptr<Expression> a, unique_ptr<Expression> b )
    -> unique_ptr<Product>
{ return unique_ptr<Product>( new Product( move( a ), move( b ) ) ); }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    auto e = sum( product( number( 5 ), number( 6 ) ), number( 7 ) );
    cout << e->eval() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Such interesting code. It's compilable or is pseudocode ? I'm unable to compile with gcc 4.8 - maybe I don't know how to enable the latest features...

Comment: @CapelliC: it's compilable, and indeed, g++ 4.8.2 was the compiler used. perhaps you didn't specify `-std=c++11`?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.2 (qmake), and apparently it doesn't accepts the flag (QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11). Not really sure about the compiler.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong - my version it's gcc version 4.6.1. I was fooled by Android NDK setting - that uses gcc 4.8 for arm, or gcc 4.8 for x86 - but didn't changed my default compiler...

Comment: @OpenLearner: in (very) older terms, pointer to functions were a reasonable compromise.